# In an international airport, is there specific set of laws for the international area?

Tags: airport, international

When travelling in an international flight, you pass a border with passport check at both the departure and the arrival airports. It means you spend time in an international area. What are the applicable laws in this area? The one from the country the airport is located in? A special set of international laws? 
Are you juridically out of any country (as if in international waters)? Is there special status with flights between countries with special immigration agreements (e.g. Shengen area)?

Comment: You might try asking this in Travel.se, they discuss transit areas of airports quite often.

Comment: @CGCampbell OK.  [[DONE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37274/in-an-international-airport-is-there-specific-set-of-laws-for-the-international)].